# Include img content in dom-to-image conversion?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I want to be able to create lots of customized playing cards using HTML and CSS, and then convert all cards (divs) to image files. I have used the dom-to-image library to do this, but the problem is that the images within the divs are not recreated. Is there a way to do this with the dom-to-image library? Or is there some easier way to turn HTML elements - including img tags - into images?

Edit: I found a way around it in a program I am using, so not in dire need of help anymore, thanks.

Comment: hi @Zuzim! welcome to SO! have you tried anything yourself? what research did you do into this topic? please provide information that will help us with helping you solve the technical problems you're running into along the way. currently this question is easily googleable and will yield plenty of results.

Comment: Thank you! Using the dom-to-image library, I have tried turning the divs into various image files (jpeg, png, svg) while letting the img tag in the div contain a png or a svg file in its src, but there is no combination that seems to be working. It seems to me when I have googled this question that what I am trying to do is rather specific and I haven't found anything that helps. At the same time I wonder if I am missing something basic here because what I want to achieve seems pretty simple, like a print screen but only of a particular HTML element.

Comment: glad you found something that works, even if it feels like a work around. could you provide the solution as an answer to your own question? this way the question can be marked as solved.

Comment: The solution was simply to use a function in the deck-builder program associated with Tabletop Simulator which I am using, which allows you to add text to images which are imported as cards in the deck you are building... so it works in this particular context, even if I would still like to be able to build the cards entirely as code.